# How to test function where return data is taken from another function?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm new to PHP Unit and now I have a dilemma.

Function structure is something like this:

```
function myfunc($arg) {
  $data = $anotherobject->myfunc2($arg);
  $diffdata = $anotherobject->myfunc3($arg);
  return $data. " ".arg. " ". $diffdata;
}
```

How can I verifiy that the output is what it should be?

Comment: Do you want to verify the func1, func2 or func3 ?

Comment: I'd like to verify that myfunc returns right data. I have a little clue that it should be done by using mock? 
It is a object oriented style actually and myfunc2 and 3 is from another object

Comment: The solution provide from @qrazi is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:
Jasir is of course also right. The point of unittesting is to test a unit as small as possible. So you would also make tests to cover myfunc2() and myfunc3().

**End of edit**

[Using a stub](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), you can set myfunc2() and myfunc3() to return a known value. You can then assert the return of myfunc as you would normally do.

Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
require_once 'SomeClass.php';

class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
           // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
           $stub = $this->getMock('SomeClass');

           // Configure the stub.
           $stub->expects($this->any())
               ->method('myfunc2')
               ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));

           $stub->expects($this->any())
               ->method('myfunc3')
               ->will($this->returnValue('bar'));

            // Calling $stub->doSomething() will now return
            // 'foo'.
            $this->assertEquals('foo somearg bar', $stub->myfunc('somearg'));
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: He's new to PHP I don't think he can handle PHPUnit testing LoL 

BTW your solution is worthy

Comment: Thanks, this made unclear things clear to me. I also understand that testing should be done func by func.

Answer (score 1):

You should test myfunc() output only. If you need to test myfunc2(), myfunct3(), make separate tests for them.

```
function test_myfunc() {
   ...
}

function test_myfunc2() {
   ...
}

function test_myfunc3() {
   ...
}
```